# HttpWebRequest/HttpResponse: How to send data in the response?

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, httpresponse

I have a client and a server.

On the client side I have:

```
HttpWebRequest request = 
    (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/fa/Default.aspx");
request.Method = "POST";                

byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(GetSAMLRequestB64());

request.ContentType = "text/xml";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
```

On the server side I have:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext) 
{
    HttpResponse response = httpContext.Response;             
    response.Clear();
    response.BufferOutput = true;
    response.StatusCode = 200; // HttpStatusCode.OK;
    response.Write("Hello");
    response.ContentType = "text/xml";
    response.End();
}
```

The client receives the response with the correct `StatusCode`. Although, if I do `(int)response.ContentLength;` on the client I get 0. I can't read the string "Hello" after I receive the response (client side).

Comment: I know this is an old thread, But may helps someone.

Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088625/net-simplest-way-to-send-post-with-data-and-read-response/19448979#19448979

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps setting the content type before the actual write or flushing the stream would help.

Comment: I did that, however there was a copy/past problem... So, still doesn't work with the content type.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't set ContentLength on the server. Maybe that would help?

Comment: how can I set the contentLength on the server?

Comment: `response.ContentLength = n;` doesn't work? If it doesn't, then I'm mistaken about `ContentLength` being your problem.