# .net post form in code behind

Tags: c#, .net

I wanna make a post form in code behind. I have simple html post is working but when I try make it WebRequest I can't make it work.

Thanks for you time in advance.

this is working >

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://www.pay-pos.com/test.php" method="post">
<textarea name="datafromuser">
<CC5Request><Name>Mert</Name><Password>123</Password><ClientId>1058</ClientId><IPAddress>213.456.654.456</IPAddress><Adress>asdsa</Adress><OrderId>123</OrderId><Type>Auth</Type>
<Number>4522115422659661</Number><ExpiresAy>01</ExpiresAy><ExpiresYil>13</ExpiresYil><Cvv2Val>123</Cvv2Val><Total>10</Total><Taksit></Taksit><Kdv>18</Kdv><BankaID>1</BankaID>
<TcKimlik>12345678912</TcKimlik></CC5Request>
</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="aaa" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This isn't working >

```
String ali = "<CC5Request><Name>Mert</Name><Password>123</Password><ClientId>xxxx</ClientId><IPAddress>213</IPAddress><Adress>asdsa</Adress>" +
                        "<OrderId>123</OrderId><Type>Auth</Type><Number>1234567891234567</Number><ExpiresAy>01</ExpiresAy><ExpiresYil>13</ExpiresYil><Cvv2Val>123</Cvv2Val>" +
                        "<Total>10</Total><Taksit></Taksit><Kdv>xx</Kdv><BankaID>1</BankaID><TcKimlik>12345678912</TcKimlik></CC5Request>";
                    WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://www.pay-pos.com/test.php?datafromuser=" + ali);
                    req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                    req.Method = "POST";
                    HttpWebResponse loWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
                    Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(1254); 

                    StreamReader loResponseStream =

                       new StreamReader(loWebResponse.GetResponseStream(), enc);

                    string lcHtml = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();
                    loWebResponse.Close();
                    loResponseStream.Close();
```

EDIT: EXPERIMENT 1

```
String postData = "Name=Mert" +
              "&Password=123" +
              "&ClientId=1058" +
              "&IPAddress=213.456.654.456" +
              "&Adress=asdsa" +
              "&OrderId=123" +
              "&Type=Auth" +
              "&Number=4522115422659661" +
              "&ExpiresAy=01" +
              "&ExpiresYil=13" +
              "&Cvv2Val=123" +
              "&Total=10" +
              "&Taksit=1" +
              "&Kdv=18" +
              "&BankaID=1" +
              "&TcKimlik=12345678912";

            string URI = "http://www.pay-pos.com/test.php";

            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            wc.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, postData);
```

EXPERIMENT 2

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.pay-pos.com/test.php");
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
        request.ContentLength = postData.Length;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.KeepAlive = false; //also tried true as well

        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
        writer.Write(postData);
        writer.Close();
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        String responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();

        response.Close();
```

EXPERIMENT 3 !!!WORKING!!!

```
String ali = "datafromuser=<CC5Request><Name>Mert</Name><Password>123</Password><ClientId>1058</ClientId><IPAddress>213.456.654.456</IPAddress><Adress>asdsa</Adress><OrderId>123</OrderId><Type>Auth</Type>" +
"<Number>4522115422659661</Number><ExpiresAy>01</ExpiresAy><ExpiresYil>13</ExpiresYil><Cvv2Val>123</Cvv2Val><Total>10</Total><Taksit></Taksit><Kdv>18</Kdv><BankaID>1</BankaID>"+
"<TcKimlik>12345678912</TcKimlik></CC5Request>";

            byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ali);

            WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://www.pay-pos.com/test.php");

            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; 
            req.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            req.Method = "POST"; 

            Stream dataStream = req.GetRequestStream(); 
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length); 
            dataStream.Close();

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            String responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();

            response.Close();
```

Comment: #3 looks nearly complete... add req.Method = "POST";

Comment: #1 and #2 aren't posting the correct form as the server is expecting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing I see wrong is that you're trying to use a query string to post the form data.  Your "form data" should be like so:

```
 String ali = "datafromuser=<CC5Request><Name>Mert</Name><Password>123</Password><ClientId>xxxx</ClientId><IPAddress>213</IPAddress><Adress>asdsa</Adress>" +
                            "<OrderId>123</OrderId><Type>Auth</Type><Number>1234567891234567</Number><ExpiresAy>01</ExpiresAy><ExpiresYil>13</ExpiresYil><Cvv2Val>123</Cvv2Val>" +
                            "<Total>10</Total><Taksit></Taksit><Kdv>xx</Kdv><BankaID>1</BankaID><TcKimlik>12345678912</TcKimlik></CC5Request>";
```

Next, you need to get the bytes[] from your form data.

```
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ali);
```

Set some headers:

```
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; 
req.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
req.Method = "POST";
```

Now write your data to the request stream.

```
Stream dataStream = req.GetRequestStream(); 
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length); 
dataStream.Close();
```

Finally... get your response.  Also note, anything that implements IDisposable should be wrapped in a `using` statement, i.e. `Stream` and `WebResponse`.

Also note that the submit button is not part of your form post data.  It's possible the server is expecting it.

Edit:  Here's a complete example from Microsoft that guides you step by step.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx

Comment: byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ali);
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http:...);
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
req.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
Stream dataStream = req.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
String responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
response.Close();
GetrequestStream line game error > Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.

Comment: @Mert - please update your answer with your new code, not overwriting the old stuff... just append it to the bottom like "Edit - tried the following and got error <your error here>

Comment: @Mert - it looks like you didn't set your request Method of "POST".  Did you delete it from your code??

Comment: works like a charm! thanks guys :) I can't thank more than this. really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you.

```
string URI = "http://www.myurl.com/post.php";
string myParamters = "param1=value1&param2=value2";

WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, myParameters);
```

Comment: I agree, WebClient would probably be much easier for a beginner.

Comment: Mert, please let me know if it helped you.

Comment: just tried sorry for late answer, response is "\n" which means we couldn't make it work :( also shouldn't I specify "datafromuser" in somehwere?

Comment: You want to make post request so you can't input parameters in url. Please provide your code, what exactly you have written.

Comment: I just edit my question and EXPERIMENT 1 is your solution I guess

Answer (score 1):

This is simples example. postData depends of form

```
String postData = "Name=" + Username +
              "&Password=" + Password +
              "&Retype=" + Password +
              "&Email=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(EmailAddress) +
              "&RealName=" + String.Format("{0}+{1}", FirstName.Replace(" ", "+"), LastName.Replace(" ", "+"));
```

Now create request and post data:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
request.ContentLength = postData.Length;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.KeepAlive = false;

StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
writer.Write(postData);
writer.Close();
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
String responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();

response.Close();
```

You can use Fiddler in order to catch how postData looks.

Comment: postData > Name=Mert&Password=123&ClientId=1058&IPAddress=213.456.654.456&Adress=asdsa&OrderId=123&Type=Auth&Number=4522115422659661&ExpiresAy=01&ExpiresYil=13&Cvv2Val=123&Total=10&Taksit=1&Kdv=18&BankaID=1&TcKimlik=12345678912      responseString  > \n  didn't work :(

Comment: Can you give me URL for which you want to do http post via code?

Comment: This is the problem with posting someone else's example.  @Mert, you need to use your element names, i.e. "datafromuser={everything in the text area}"

Comment: Danilo Vulović on top Question you can find working html example there is everything you need. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
   {

       byte[] response = client.UploadValues("http://dork.com/service", new NameValueCollection()
       {
           { "home", "Cosby" },
           { "favorite+flavor", "flies" }
       });
   }
```

You will need these includes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Net;
```

If you're insistent on using a static method/class:

```
public static class Http
{
    public static byte[] Post(string uri, NameValueCollection pairs)
    {
        byte[] response = null;
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            response = client.UploadValues(uri, pairs);
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

Then simply:

```
Http.Post("http://dork.com/service", new NameValueCollection() {
    { "home", "Cosby" },
    { "favorite+flavor", "flies" }
});
```

Comment: Ref Url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088625/net-simplest-way-to-send-post-with-data-and-read-response   for above