# Handle POST and GET in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to develop a program that handles POST and GET requests.

I've spent countless hours searching around the web for a tutorial that doesn't depend on ASP.NET *I do not want to use ASP.NET just standard C#*.

How can I achieve this? The furthest I've gotten to is this:

```
if (HttpMethod.ContentType == "POST") {
  // Code here
}
```

I've made a function HttpListen server on `http://localhost:8080/` which sends a response.

What I'm looking for is you do `http://localhost:8080/?method=val1&results=val2`.

Thanks, Brown.

Comment: What you are looking for, is creating a http library in c#. Have you searched for something similar?

Comment: I've searched everyone thing related to Http. I cannot seem to find anything.

Comment: Well, you'd have to start an application which listens on port 80, then study `http` protocols, and go from there. The code snippet you've put there doesn't really tell us anything about your current state... it doesn't relate to handling requests at all, it's part of the code you'd write once you've got the server implemented..

Comment: I've done. I've made a functional Http Listen server.

Comment: have you check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394229/net-post-form-in-code-behind ?, if it's somehow related to your concern?

Comment: @FrancisSaul As I said, I don't want anything to do with ASP.NET.

Comment: @brownzilla If you've made a functional Http server, I'm not sure what you're stuck on..?

Comment: I'm stuck on actually handling a post method like `http://localhost:8080/?method=val1&results=val2`

Comment: @brownzilla That's a get method, not a post method. In any case, you should read up on the http spec, it'll tell you exactly what to do and how to parse the query string.

Comment: Could you possibly provide a link for a recommended site.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for an HTTP server library that is not ASP.NET?

Awkwardly bypassing the question "What's wrong with ASP.NET?"....

[Nancy](http://nancyfx.org/) is an awesome lightweight open source library. You can find some [samples on github](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy.Demo.Samples/tree/master/src/Nancy.Demo.Samples), although the samples are a bit on the heavy side. If you're looking for an extremely basic setup you can get away with a couple dozen lines of code. A good example is the console-based [self-hosted](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Self-Hosting-Nancy) sample.

```
// add such a module class to your assembly, Nancy should find it automagically
public class ResourceModule : NancyModule
{
    public ResourceModule() : base("/products")
    {
        // would capture routes to /products/list sent as a GET request
        Get["/list"] = parameters => {
            return "The list of products";
        };
    }
}

// then start the host
using (var host = new NancyHost(new Uri("http://localhost:1234")))
{
   host.Start();
   // do whatever other work needed here because once the host is disposed of the server is gone 
   Console.ReadLine();
}
```