# C# error message when trying to use System.Net.Http.Post

Tags: c#

I am developing Windows 8 app. Error message "The type or namespace name 'Post' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net.Http' (are you missing an assembly reference?)" is coming in Visual Studio 2012 when I try to execute the code

```
byte[] response = System.Net.Http.Post
  (
      url: "someurl",
      contentType: "application/json",
      contentLength: 32,
      content: "pqpUserName=admin&password=test@123"
  );
```

The code is from the URL [.NET: Simplest way to send POST with data and read response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088625/net-simplest-way-to-send-post-with-data-and-read-response/15129678#15129678)

. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This code is too old, take advantage of new toy: HttpClient http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx

Comment: Does it provide Post or equivalent functionality?

Comment: @Cuong Le Could u provide equivalent code of HttpClient for the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx):

```
var client = new HttpClient();

var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("pqpUserName", "admin"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "test@123")
                };

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);

var response = client.PostAsync("yourURI", content).Result;

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{}
```

Comment: Could u be specific on how to get response from client.PostAsync("yourURI", content);

Comment: Hey, The above code is working in Windows store app. But, HttpClient is not available in Windows Phone SDK. Any idea about the equivalent code for the above code in Windows Phone SDK 8.0?

Comment: I have raised a new question regarding this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15198936/windows-phone-sdk-post-request

Answer (score 4):

Add the `System.Net.Http.HttpMethod` namespace to your code.

Comment: getting error "Non-invocable member 'System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Post' cannot be used like a method."

Comment: `HttpMethod` is an enumeration, not a method, so yes, you're getting this error because you're not using it correctly.