# Send post data and get status code

Tags: c#

I need to know how to send this as post data in C#.

The following is in python, and I need to convert it to C# code and send it as a webrequests.

```
post = {'customer_fid': self.customer_fid, 'salt': self.salt, 'token': token, 'customer_facebooktoken': self.customer_facebooktoken}

request = self.session.post(self.baseurl + self.loginurl, data=post)
```

This should be done with either webrequests or httpclient. But I don't know how to do it. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't know.. That's nice :) But what have you tried? This site doesn't work like "I don't know, you give me the code". Show your effort, we provide the help. HttpClient is a good place to start.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx

Comment: Nope i haven't tried. I can't see the logic of the syntax. That's why im asking here.

Answer (score 0):

[Have a look on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/http-request-with-post)
[or this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088625/net-simplest-way-to-send-post-with-data-and-read-response)

[or this](http://developer.nirvanix.com/forums/p/56/126.aspx)

Hope this will help you.