# Post data not getting across to my api page

Tags: c#, httpclient, json.net

I have the following. It reaches an api page I have set up in PHP... spot on. yum yum... no probs.

```
    public static async Task<string> GetData(string url, string data)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        StringContent queryString = new StringContent(data);            

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(url), queryString);

        //response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return responseBody;
    }
```

string data is actually a JSON.NET representation of an object with various properties.
On my PHP page I am taking a look at one of those properties "username".
So let's say I send the following info:

```
public class PostContent
{
    public string username { get; set; }
}

PostContent data = new PostContent { username = "dooby" };

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postData);
return PostRequest.GetData(AuthURL, json);
```

On my PHP page I make a request to the post data $_POST["username"]... and nothing comes out in the response. If I output some random string to make sure I'm accessing the correct page, I get the string correctly.

[image]

So the POST data is not coming through... What am I do doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is not very clearly written, from what I can understand it looks like you are POSTing some JSON data from a C# client to a PHP server, and your PHP code is not able to read the data from the request when it is received from the client.  Is that the issue?

If so, I think the problem might be that you are not setting the `Content-Type` header when you make the request to the server.  The [documentation for the `StringContent` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158908.aspx) says that the default content type is `text/plain`.  Since you are sending JSON data, you should specify a content type of `application/json`.  The server will probably not be able to parse the data correctly if it does not know what kind of data you are sending.

Try initializing your `queryString` variable like this:

```
StringContent queryString = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to do the trick perfectly. I found it on someone elses stackoverflow page: [.NET: Simplest way to send POST with data and read response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088625/net-simplest-way-to-send-post-with-data-and-read-response/15129678#comment28097099_15129678)

```
It works like a charm! I'll make this answer better when I get home

var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("postdataproperty", "blabla"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("postdataproperty2", "blabla2"),
}

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent( pairs );
```