# WebClient to invoke Solr DataImportHandler not working

Tags: .net, solr, webclient, dataimporthandler

I need to schedule a Windows task that will invoke `Solr DataImportHandler` command. So I decided to create a console app which will invoke the `DataImportHandler` command using `WebClient`. However, this simple code does not seem to work for me. The `uri` works independently but not from the console app.  What am I doing wrong? Please help. (I have tried DownloadString as well).

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{              
    var uri = "http://localhost:8983/solr/#/collection1/dataimport//dataimport?command=full-import&clean=true&commit=true";
    client.OpenRead(uri);               
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use dataimport scheduler (expained in DIH wiki page)?

Comment: That is a Java based program, right? My area is .Net and it will perhaps take me a long time to get that up and running. Getting Solr started took me a while.

Comment: Ups, did not check. You can try using UploadValues method instead of OpenRead and prepare NameValueCollection with your Url params), like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4088699/465710