# Send a file in a POST coming from the return of a MVC Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

It is a bit confusing to explain what I need, but I will try....

In the image below the **browse button** selects a file and the **Upload button** sends the file in a **post  method**, but in some cases I need to process the file changing it to adapt for my importation, so I have created the **"Convert file option"**.

[image]

The convert file option changes a file and sends it back to the user by downloading it again, then the user will import this file through my **Upload button**.

I need to get this FileContentResult not as a download, but sending this processed file through my other POST method and upload this automatically.

How can I get the File result and send it straight to my other POST?

I know that it is a completly weird behaviour, but I cannot change my Upload method as this redirects to another application which gets the post.

```
public FileContentResult ConvertFile()
{
    var file = Request.Files[0];
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        /// my code... memorystream..etc..
        return new FileContentResult(memoryStream.ToArray(), "text/csv") { FileDownloadName = "abc.csv" };
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you extract some logic from the other POST and put it to another method, which can be used in `ConvertFile()` method?

Comment: My other POST method, is redirecting to another application, I don't have access to its code, the only thing I have is the submit button and the URL of the other method. For instance:   url../otherapplication/uploadfile

Comment: 'Posting from POST' is generally problematic. You can check following link for ideas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088625/net-simplest-way-to-send-post-with-data-and-read-response, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/http-request-with-post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/http-request-with-post) 
 Hope this will help you.

Also, see the MSDN sample [Click here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx)

You can also use the third party libraries to deal with these problems like Restsharp etc., show some efforts.