# How can I bypass the "Too Long" error from WebClient.DownloadString()?

Tags: c#, pdf, base64, uri

I'm trying to make a download request from an API which requires me to include the Base64 String of a PDF in the URL. I'm using the WebClient.DownloadString() method and it gives me a System.IO.PathTooLongException.

I know there's a limit on the characters in the URI (~60k) and my URI are a couple thousand above that, so I don't think setting a base url or anything would help. Is there any way to bypass the URI character limit?

Comment: why you are passing url as URI as its constructor is overloaded it also accepts string . .

Comment: I'm just passing a string url to the method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the System.IO.PathTooLongException is thrown by the WebClient as a result of a HTTP [414](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.15) error? If thats the case, the server does not allow get-requests of that length.

Are you sure that you have to add the pdf data as a GET-parameter? 
Try POSTing the data like this:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    var nvc = new NameValueCollection();
    nvc.Add("pdf-parameter", "encoded-pdf-here");
    // UploadValues uses 'POST' by default
    var data = wc.UploadValues(url, nvc);
    // Adjust result encoding if required...
    var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
}
```

Comment: I tried using the method from the answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088625/net-simplest-way-to-send-post-with-data-and-read-response and it works perfect. Thanks for the suggestion.