# (400) Bad Request -> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wsdl

I've a code block like this:

```
        const string webServiceUrl = "https://test.xyxyx.com/App/Services/wService.svc?wsdl";
        var postString = string.Format("Parameter1={0}&Parameter2={1}&Parameter3={2}&Parameter4={3}&Parameter5={4}&Parameter6={5}&Parameter7={6}&Parameter8={7}", "AA", "AB", "AC", "BA", "BB", BC, 5, 7);

        const string contentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(webServiceUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = contentType;
        webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";

        StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());
        requestWriter.Write(postString);
        requestWriter.Close();

        StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        var responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        responseReader.Close();
        webRequest.GetResponse().Close();
```

I get the error on this line:

```
StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
```

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

Why I get this? I tried some different methods, but result is the same. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're posting to `?wsdl` url.

Also, your content is not xml.

Generally, you can examine the content of the returned page, it may have some more details.

Finally check out [.NET: Simplest way to send POST with data and read response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088625/net-simplest-way-to-send-post-with-data-and-read-response) .

Comment: I get this: Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'. how can I set the content-type by 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' for this method?